# How to put piped input into a variable

Tags: bash, shell-script, pipe, variable

I'm new to bash so this should be pretty basic but I can't find it so far.

I am going to have an input

```
cat input_file | sh_file.sh output_file
```

I want to get the information from the `input_file` so that I can use the `sh_file.sh` to pass it on to a python file and do some manipulation and output it from python.

I know that if it was set up like

```
sh_file.sh input_file output_file
```

I could just use `input_file=$1`, `output_file=$2` and pass those through to my python file but with the pipe I don't know how to store it in a variable.

Comment: What exactly is it that you want to store in a variable, the *contents* of the file, or the *name* of the file (or something else)? Also, how does the python file handle the input file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside the shell script, do this:

```bsh
data=$(cat)
```

that will use the `cat` command to read standard input and store the result in the `$data` variable.

Read about the `$(...)` syntax here: [3.5.4 Command Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution)

Comment: I thought this worked but it's actually only giving me the first word in my input. If I type ````cat filename```` it gives me the correct output, but for some reason using this cuts off all except for the first word

Comment: Exactly how are you using the `"$data"` variable? I'm guessing that you are using the variable unquoted.

Comment: That worked! Thank you!